# ReactJS : Nested navigations not works, not reaching the expected page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Using React `^16.13.1` and react-router-dom `^5.2.0`, We have multiple Navigation files to make nested navigation, the first `Navigation.js` runs and redirects fine, but the second `Navigation.js` does not work as we expected.

Created a react APP using `npx create-react-app nested`

Listing the important files for review:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navigation />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import nestedNavigation from "./nested/Navigation";
const NotFound = () => <h1>Not Found</h1>;
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/welcome" component={nestedNavigation} />
        <Route path="/" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

**nested/Navigation.js** nested navigation - the second one

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter,
  useRouteMatch,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Welcome from "../Welcome"

const Navigation = () => {
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    debugger;
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}/nested`} exact component={Welcome} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Shouldn't your Route @nested/Navigation.js have path set to `${path}/nested`?

Comment: @user0101, Yes, I tried the above but getting same issues, `<Route path={'${path}/nested'} exact component={Welcome} />
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested routes require the full path in the most recent full release version of React Router, add the rest of the URL from the upper components to the path prop. [codesandbox from react-router Docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzy12)

Also remove the exact from your welcome. Sub-routes wont likely work with exact because they aren’t exactly that route!

Comment: You mean the `path` or complete URL?, I added the path but still getting the same issues, I have updated the question.

Comment: The codesandbox shows using the ‘url’ from useRouteMatch in the underlying routes, both path. Would align to docs first

Comment: I’ve updated my answer - but remove the exact from the welcome path too. This is likely preventing routing